# How can I search multiple files for a string in Perl?

Tags: perl

My question is probably simple but I'm a complete newbie. I want to search the contents of multiple text files for a particular phrase and then display the lines of the finds on screen. I've already learnt how to deal with a single file. For example, if I want to search for a word, say "Okay" in a text file named "wyvern.txt" in the root directory of F. The following code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = 'F:\wyvern.txt';
open(txt, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
  print "$line" if $line =~ /Okay/;
}
close(txt);
```

But what should I do if I want to search for the same phrase in two text files, say "wyvern' and "casanova" respectively? or how about all the files in the directory "novels" in the root directory of F.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Mike

**Edit:**

Haha, I finally figured out how to search all the files in a directory for a pattern match:)
The following code works great:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
@files = <F:/novels/*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
open   (FILE, "$file");
while($line= <FILE> ){
print "$line" if $line =~ /Okay/;
}
close FILE; 
}
```

Comment: Do you really need it to be in Perl?  You can Google how to use grep for this if you are on a Unix-like OS.

Comment: I don't think they are, given the path in `$file`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extending the good answer provided by Jonathan Leffler:

The filename where the match was found is in `$ARGV`, and with a small change, the line number can be found in `$.`. Example:

```
while (<>) {
  print "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /pattern/;
} continue {
  close ARGV if eof; # Reset $. at the end of each file.
}
```

Furthermore, if you have a list of filenames and they're not on the commandline, you can still get the magic `ARGV` behavior. Watch:

```
{
  local @ARGV = ('one.txt', 'two.txt');
  while (<>) {
    print "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /Okay/;
  } continue {
    close ARGV if eof;
  }
}
```

Which is a generally useful pattern for doing line-by-line processing on a series of files, whatever it is -- even if I might recommend `File::Grep` or `App::Ack` for this *specific* problem :)

Comment: Thank you hobbs! The code works perfectly and now I can search multiple files for a specified string :)
---------------
#!/usr/bin/perl
{
  local @ARGV = ('F:\wyvern.txt', 'F:\casanova.txt');
  while (<>) {
    print "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /Okay/;
  } continue {
    close ARGV if eof;
  }
}
------------------------

But what should I do if I want to search all the files in a specified directory, say "novels" in the drive F?

Comment: Look at `glob()` to get files in one directory, and `File::Find::Object` or `File::Find::Rule` to find files in subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you, hobbs! Things seem to be getting interesting for a beginner like me:)

Answer (score 4):

On a system where command line arguments are properly expanded, you can use:

```
[sinan@host:~/test]$ perl -ne 'print "$.:$_" if /config/' *
1:$(srcdir)/config/override.m4
```

The problem with Windows is:

```
C:\Temp> perl -ne "print if /perl/" *.txt
Can't open *.txt: Invalid argument.
```

On Windows, you could do:

```
C:\Temp> for %f in (*.txt) do perl -ne "print if /perl/" %f
```

But, you might just want to use `cmd.exe` builtin [findstr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) or the [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) command line tool.

Comment: How can I use the Windows perl-code and write the output into a text-File instead to the terminal? ... and thanks for this very useful code.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to list the files on the command line, and then simply use:

```
while (<>)
{
    print if m/Okay/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[File::Grep](http://search.cpan.org/~mneylon/File-Grep-0.02/Grep.pm) is what you need here

Comment: The documentation of File::Grep is too compact for those being new to it, do you maybe know a tutorial for beginners?

Answer (score 2):

Just a tweak on your line: `<F:/novels/*>`, I prefer to use the `glob` keyword - it works the same in this context and avoids the chances of confusing the many different uses of angle brackets in perl. Ie:

`@files = glob "F:/novels/*";`

See [perldoc glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

put the files in a for loop, or something along those lines:

i.e.

```
for $file ('F:\wyvern.txt','F:\casanova.txt') {

open(TXT, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
     print "$line" if $line =~ /Okay/;
    }
close TXT;
}
```

Comment: @Lazy Bob, I changed ($line = <txt>) to ($line = <TXT>) and retested the code again. It works great. Thanks for sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm a complete dummie. But to sum up, I now can search one single text file or multiple text files for a specified string. I'm still trying to figuring out how to deal with all the files in one folder.
the following codes work.

### Code 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file = 'F:\one.txt';
open(txt, $file);
while($line = <txt>) {
  print "$line" if $line =~ /Okay/;
}
close(txt);
```

---

### Code 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
{
  local @ARGV = ('F:\wyvern.txt', 'F:\casanova.txt');
  while (<>) {
    print "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /Okay/;
  } continue {
    close ARGV if eof;
  }
}
```

---

Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.